# Mail with gmail: labels get lost occasionally

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I am using **Mail** with two **gmail** accounts and I am using **labels** to archive my messages.

All my gmail labels show up as folders in Mail. I then use Mail to move emails from the inbox into respective folders, and if I check in the gmail web interface, I see the labels that I have applied in mail.

This works quite well in general, however, sometimes (this happens after I click on a folder within mail to see the mails with this label), **suddenly all mails that I moved from my inbox into a folder re-appear in my inbox. When I look into gmail, I see that the labels are lost**.

I have read that, depending on the OS X version, the gmail option **show in imap** should be enabled/disabled. I have version 10.9.4, and since I cannot see new mail in **Mail** when disabled, I have this option enabled.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the loss of my labels? I would like to keep a clean inbox and just archived 300 messages which are now back in the inbox!

Comment: Just to clarify. You are aware that the Label meaning in gmail is same as Folder. So if you want to see them in your mail you have to enable the IMAP.  So creating new labels in gmail will result in Folders in Mail.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and I have IMAP enabled. Viewing the labels as folders works well and when I move mails into folders, they get labelled in gmail. Just sometimes when I click into a folder in Mail and then select the inbox again, all mails are moved back into inbox and when I check in the gmail web interface, I see that the labels are lost.